# Variables from switch statement outside

Tags: java, variables, combobox, switch-statement

I am writing a program which contains ComboBox where you choose text and this text will be converted to coefficient using switch statment in program. The problem is that I can't use varible outside switch statment. I really appreciate if someone could help.

Code sample:

```
double Cst1; 
String s = Cst.getSelectedItem().toString();

switch (s) { 

     case "ABC":
         Cst1 = -25;
         break;

     case "CBA":
         Cst1 = -10;
         break;

     case "BCA":
         Cst1 = 0;      
         break;

     case "ACB":
         Cst1 = 10;             
         break;

     default:
         answer.setText("ERROR");
         break;                     
}

double C14 = 9 * Cst1;
```

Comment: Use which variable? It's scoped outside the switch.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I can't use varible outside switch statment"?

Comment: This code will not compile since Cst1 may not be initialized.

Comment: try initializig the variable: double Cst1 = -1; before the switch

Comment: the question is incomplete, please share the exception output or compile out put.

Comment: OP needs to post the actual error or way this is failing instead of watching a flurry of guesses for what problem OP might be having go by.

Comment: I can't get answer of C14, beacause of Cst1.

Comment: Almost unbelievable ;) 'cause `Cst1` can't even get null. So what or where does the error happen? Do you have a stack trace or any other unexpected result?

Comment: `Cst1` doesn't have a value if you go through the default switch case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string value that isn't explicitly covered in your switch, `Cst1` will never be initialized. For example, the string `"AAA"` will fall into the default case.

There are two possible fixes:

1. Initialize Cst1 like

   ```
   double Cst1 = 0.
   ```
2. Set Cst1 in your default case like

   ```
   default:
       Cst1 = 0.;
       // Display your error
       break;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you get an error which says that the variable is not initialized, try this:

```
double Cst1 = 0.;
```